# Kotlin - how to pass in null value into fragments newInstance method?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have created a fragment using Kotlin and you know how there is a convenience static method to set the fragment args in Java. Like this:

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(Bundle args){
    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

I'm trying to accomplish this in Kotlin using a companion object since it's static. Here is what I have so far which compiles:

```
companion object {
    fun newInstance(@Nullable b: Bundle): MyFragment {
        val frag = MyFragment()
        frag.arguments = b
        return frag
    }
}
```

I was thinking that if I use the `@Nullable` annotation that I would be allowed to pass in null for the bundle but I keep getting the following error when I call `MyFragment.newInstance(null)`:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                        Process: com.mobile.MyApp.labs, PID: 5758
>                                                                        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter b
>                                                                            at com.mobile.MyApp.ui.cart.fragments.MyFragment$Companion.newInstance(MyFragment.kt:0)
>                                                                            at com.mobile.MyApp.ui.cart.fragments.CartDetailsFragment.onCtaClicked(CartDetailsFragment.java:521)
>                                                                            at com.mobile.MyApp.ui.cart.fragments.CartDetailsFragment_ViewBinding$1.doClick(CartDetailsFragment_ViewBinding.java:66)
>                                                                            at butterknife.internal.DebouncingOnClickListener.onClick(DebouncingOnClickListener.java:22)
>                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
>                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

How can I pass in `null` ?

Comment: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/nullable-as-argument/1884

Comment: this wont work in my case. as i if i pass in null i still want the fragment to be created and returned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Kotlin, you don't pass `@Nullable` but rather write a question mark (`?`) behind the type name to mark it nullable.

```
fun newInstance(b: Bundle?): MyFragment
```

Comment: Also, have a look at the official docs about null safety in Kotlin: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin provide (?) FOR handling `null`.have look

```
companion object {
    fun newInstance( b: Bundle?): MyFragment {
        val frag = MyFragment()
        frag.arguments = b
        return frag
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you.